# C++ SetKeys( _T("d") no funciona

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de usar el método setKeys()
Si asigno la letra “d”, al CMFCRibbonButton con el método setKeys, el shortcut no funciona, pero si cambio la letra a cualquier otra, por ejemplo “u”, funciona.

Me gustaría saber porque esto pasa o si hay alguna limitante con la letra “d” o si debo darle algún formato específico?

```
CMFCRibbonButton* pBtnDelete = new CMFCRibbonButton( ID_BTN_MENU_DELETE, title, IconDelete, -1 );
pBtnDelete->SetKeys( _T("d") );
```

Comment: Mr. Castro, your post must be in spanish. Please translate it, otherwise it will be closed. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta al castellano, porque esto es [es.so] y es el idioma oficial del sitio. Saludos

Comment: ¿Puede ser que ya esté mapeada esa tecla en otra opción?

Comment: No, ya revise todo el codigo y no, solo ahi esta mapeada